# Why i have HEAP CORUPTION in this simple code?

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-corruption

I have function which converts Hex String to Byte Array,

```
BYTE* HexStrToByteArray(std::wstring hex_str)
{
    int len = hex_str.size()*0.5f;
    BYTE *bytearray = new BYTE[len];
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    {
        swscanf(hex_str.c_str() + 2*i, L"%02x", &bytearray[i]);
    }
    return bytearray;
}
```

In code i use it like this

```
BYTE *byte_array = HexStrToByteArray(hex_str);
```

for now function work fine, but when i try release memory, allocated in function

```
delete [] byte_array;//HEAP CORUPTION ERROR
```

I have HEAP CORUPTION error... What i do wrong?

Comment: `int len = hex_str.size()*0.5f;` -- using `int` for sizes is a terrible idea, especially when combined with inherently non-exact floating-point computations. That line ought to be `std::size_t len = hex_str.size() / 2;`.

Comment: +1 You're effectively going from `size_t` to `float` to `int`, while you can have all as `size_t`.

Comment: I think that `hex_str.c_str() + 2*i` is buggy (at least not safe) because of unicodeness but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Johan It's fine as long as the string is really just a couple of hexadecimal characters (== representable in ASCII).

Comment: @Johan See my answer for a number of fixes (there are many things wrong with your code).

Comment: @Johan Um, sorry, I meant OP... whatever.

Comment: Please notice 'std::size_t len = (hex_str.size() + 1) / 2;' in the answer of @H2CO3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `valgrind` on your code reveals the problem pretty quickly:

```
Invalid write of size 4
==34783==    by 0x21B719: swscanf
Address 0x100004000 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 3 alloc'd
```

I've got this error when I ran your code on a hex string of length 6:

```
BYTE *ba = HexStrToByteArray(L"123456");
```

Which, of course, is supposed to produce 3 bytes. However, the `%02x` conversion specifier makes `swscanf()` expect a pointer to `unsigned int` (which happens to be 4 bytes long on your implementation), whereas you are passing it a `BYTE *`, which is presumably a pointer to `unsigned char` instead.

---

Instead of trying to mess around with `scanf()`, which is horrible, use `strtoul()`. Also, use `std::size_t` for sizes, and **please don't pollute integer operations with floating-point numbers.** Furthermore, if your hexadecimal string is of an odd number of characters, you will need to allocate one extra byte for it. In addition, I suggest you pass the input string by const reference to avoid unnecessary copies.

```
BYTE *HexStrToByteArray(const std::wstring &hex_str)
{
    std::size_t len = (hex_str.size() + 1) / 2;
    char buf[3] = { 0 };
    BYTE *bytearray = new BYTE[len];

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        buf[0] = hex_str[2 * i + 0];
        buf[1] = hex_str[2 * i + 1];
        bytearray[i] = std::strtoul(buf, NULL, 16);
    }

    return bytearray;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `"%02x"` format spec expects an `unsigned int` value to write into, so instead of writing a single byte in each loop iteration it's writing 4 bytes.

So you're writing past the end of the allocated `bytearray`.

Answer (score 1):

You're just using the wrong format specifier for your `swscanf`, so writing four bytes for every hex pair. Use the `hh` argument type modifier. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Try this instead.

```
swscanf(hex_str.c_str() + 2*i, L"%02hhx", &bytearray[i]);
```

As others have said, this is a pretty poor way to implement this function, anyway.